# Regular parametrisations of surfaces and diffeomorphisms

Tags: calculus, surfaces, diffeomorphism

I am stuck at the following exercise:

> Let $f:D \subset \mathbb{R}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ with $k \le n$ be a regular parametrisation and let $\sigma: \mathbb{R}^k \rightarrow D$ be a diffeomorphism. Prove that $\hat{f} = f \circ \sigma$ is a regular parametrisation.

I realise that I only have to show that $rk(D\hat{f}) = k$, but I do not know how to do that. Things would be easy if a diffeomorphism was linear, but we can not assume that here. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: HINT: the chain rule gives you a formula for $D\hat f$.

Comment: With chain rule you mean: $D\hat{f}= D(f\circ\sigma)(x) = Df(\sigma(x)) \cdot D\sigma(x)$? How does this help? I only know that $rk(Df(\sigma(x))) = k$, but I do not know the rank of the other matrix.

Comment: Yes, that's it. You have enough information on both matrices to conclude. This is now a simple problem of linear algebra.

Comment: I am sorry but I really do not get it. Do you use any facts about the rank of $D_\sigma (x)$?

Comment: The Jacobian matrix of $\sigma$ is invertible.

Comment: Now I see thanks a lot.